# How to show slideToggle closed by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, slidetoggle

I am creating a menu with sub menu which opens sub-menu with slideToggle. By default it is shows the sub-menu, please tell me that how it will show only menu and not sub menu links by default.

```
<span>Natural Rubber Reclaim</span>
  <ul>
  <div id="product_tabs">
     <li><a href='products.html'><span>Whole Tyre Reclaim</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='inner_tube_reclaim.html'><span>Inner Tube Reclaim</span></a></li>
  </div>
  </ul>


<span><a href='synthatic_reclaim_rubber.html'>Synthatic Reclaim Rubber</a></span>
<a href='products_5.html'><span>Crumb Rubber</span></a>
```

Rubber Compounds

and this is the toggle code I am using

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.accordion:eq(0)> span').click(function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion:eq(0) > span').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('.accordion:eq(0) > span').next().hide()
});
```

another solution will be is to simulate the click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion:eq(0) > span').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    }).click();
});
```